For the stable 3-cycle in the logistic map, where are the other cycles?
According to Sharkovsky's theorem, the existence of a 3-cycle means there will also exist cycles of all periods. In the logistic map, with the stable 3-cycle that starts at 1 + sqrt(8) with superstable point at 3.83187... I understand that the other cycles would be unstable / repellant points. From attempting to read the different proofs of Sharkovsky's theorem, my sense is that most of the points in the higher order cycles would be clustered fairly close together. Is that accurate? If so, where are they? Or is that innacurate, and all the other cycles are scattered throughout the [0,1] range? Any resources you'd care to point me at would be very much appreciated as well. The most helpful one I've found so far is this video on "Why are periodic systems so unpredictable?": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCuiwCM-AQ8&t=1031s

One thing to keep in mind is that due to the folding nature of the map, in floating-point numbers optimistically 1 bit of accuracy is lost in each iteration. Which means that in comparing exact and numerical implementation (64bit double precision), the numerical orbit has lost any connection to the exact orbit after 53 iterations. This limits the numerical computation of cycles. Of course one can employ multi-precision numbers to push back that limit.

Let $f(x)=ax(1-x)$ be the logistic map with parameter $a$. The easiest way to visually detect a five-cycle is to graph $y=x,y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{(5)}(x)$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-fold composition of $f$. Taking $a=3.83187$ for specificity, we obtain the following diagram:

Each crossing between $y=x$ in blue and $y=f^{(5)}(x)$ in green is a solution to $f^{(5)}(x)=x$. Of these crossings, two also intersect with $y=f(x)$ and thus corresponds to a fixed point $f(x)=x$. (Specifically, it's the fixed points $x=0,1-1/a$.) The remaining ten intersections correspond to two five-cycles. Numerically, they sort out as follows:
$$\{0.216881, 0.650818, 0.870807, 0.431094, 0.939774\},\quad \{0.237384, 0.693695, 0.814205, 0.579667,0.933647\}$$
Similarly, if we replace $f^{(5)}(x)$ with $f^{(7)}(x)$ then we get the graph below:

From this we count 28 nontrivial crossings and thus four distinct 7-cycles. So we indeed have both 5- and 7-cycles. We could similarly use $f^{(3)}(x)$ instead to deduce the presence of two 3-cycles. We might think to proceed with larger cycles, but if we want to find 9-cycles then we need to discard not only the two fixed points but also the three period-three points. So we would need to consider four graphs at once, with $y=f^{(n)}(x)$ being very hard to parse. As such the graphical approach does not scale well and I will stop here.

One thing to add here is that the period-5 and period-7 points do visually tend to cluster in pairs, but each of the overall cycles are spread across the entire interval $(-1,1)$.

THANK YOU!!! That is an awesome response. So grateful. Well done.

This graphical line of reasoning also applies to other iterative maps. The tent map is particularly nice, since repeated iteration still yields a piecewise linear function (albeit a very complicated one).
